# Sorting text lines from hard drive files by partly loading to memory | Java

Tags: java

My task is to sort file which is too large to fit in memory. File contains text lines.
What I did:

1. read from original file by parts (of allowed size).
2. sorted each part
3. saved each sorted part to tempfiles

As I understand next thing i should do is:

1. read first lines of each file
2. sort them between each other (use local variable to temporarily store it, but I am not sure if it will be below restricted size)
3. write first line (as result of sorting) to final file
4. now I need to remove line I just wrote from temporary file
5. now i need to repeat steps 1-4 until all lines are sorted and "transferred" from temp files to final file

I am most unsure about step 4 - is there a class than can look for a value and then erase line with this value (at that point I won't even know from which file that line came)? I think that this is not a proper way to reach my goal at all. But I need to remove lines which are already sorted. And I can't operate with files' data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to do this in Java (assuming by the tag)? As memory wise it isn't going to be efficient way. The simplest option in my opinion would be using `sort` and just sort the file directly on the OS level.

This article will give you a guide on how to use sort: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-command-linuxunix-examples/

Sort is available on Windows as well as unix/linux and can handle huge files.

Comment: Have you looked at this previous posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649567/sorting-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: Also this is an alternative approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275208/sort-huge-file-in-java